# Iterating over an array of objects and mapping them with custom key names in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plyr.js

I am trying to loop through an array of objects and assign them as props to the react Plyr component here is what i am doing currently i'm just passing the first object values as props to the components like so.

```
    if (movie) {
        console.log(movie.video_info[0].src)
        videoSrc = {
            type: 'video',
            title: 'Example title',
            sources: [
                {
                    size: movie.video_info[0].quality,
                    src: movie.video_info[0].source
                }
            ]
        }
    };
```

here is my api response

```
"video_info": [
    {
        "quality": "1080",
        "video_url": "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4",
        "id": "1111"
    },
    {
        "quality": "720",
        "video_url": "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4",
        "id": "1112"
    }
]
```

here is what the structure of the plyr object is [link to plyr io](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#the-source-setter).

I am still new to React and i did try using for each and map but i was not able to change the key names basically i want to store the key values from the api response and assign them to custom keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```js
let a = movie.video_info.map( v => {
    return {
        type:'video',
        title: 'Example title',
        sources: [{
            size: v.quality,
            src: v.video_url
        }]
    }
})

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean. mapping over an array of sources?

```js
let sources = movie.video_info
                   .map((vidInfo)=>({
                       size: vidInfo.quality,
                       src: vidInfo.source
                     }))

let videoSrc = {
            type: 'video',
            title: 'Example title',
            sources
        }
```